# Android Accesibility system-wide zoom controlled via Keyboard?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am developing an accessibility based application which lets users use the application using a bluetooth keyboard, hands-free. What I need now is for the users to be able to zoom in and out, in the application(and possibly the whole android system) using certain key-combo(say Ctrl+Alt+?).

The zoom should work something like the [Magnification Gesture](http://www.techdecoded.com/?p=161) feature of the android accessibility settings.The magnification on that works on triple-tap to activate(which I want to activate by a certain key-combo) and pan around using two finger swipe( Which probably would be the direction keys from keyboard).

The only thing I have found even remotely related to doing something like this is the Android [Accesibility Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html). But I dont think it let's me get keyboard key-combo and then zoom-in the screen.

Is there any way we can do this in Android? Do I need to go AOSP and make my own Android OS version probably? Please help!